# Form theming datetime widget Symfony 2

Tags: symfony, twig

I like to 'form-theme' my datetime widget in my form. 
I have created a fields.html.twig file with this in it:

```
{% block datetime_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
    <div {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>
        {{ '{{ day }}-{{ month }}-{{ year }}'|replace({
            '{{ day }}': form_widget(form.day),
            '{{ month }}': form_widget(form.month),
            '{{ year }}': form_widget(form.year),
        })|raw }}
        {{ form_widget(form.hour, { 'attr': { 'size': '1' } }) }} : {{ form_widget(form.minute, { 'attr': { 'size': '1' } }) }} : {{ form_widget(form.second, { 'attr': { 'size': '1' } }) }}
    </div>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock datetime_widget %}
```

I've entered this line in my form view template

```
{% form_theme form 'AcmeDashboardBundle:Form:fields.html.twig' %}
```

The datetime widget gets rendered. But the date and time parts are in a separate div element. Which breaks the widget in 2 lines. I'd like to display the date and time part next to each other.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To achieve this you must redefine either the datetime_widget without using the built in date_widget & time_widget (because they are each wrapped with divs) or you can redefine the date_widget & time_widget to remove their wrapping divs.

Here's how to implement the first option:

```
{% extends 'form_div_layout.html.twig' %}

{% block datetime_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% if widget == 'single_text' %}1
        {{ block('field_widget') }}
    {% else %}
        <div {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>
            {{ form_errors(form.date.year) }}
            {{ form_errors(form.date.month) }}
            {{ form_errors(form.date.day) }}
            {{ form_errors(form.time) }}
            {{ form_widget(form.date.year) }}
            {{ form_widget(form.date.month) }}
            {{ form_widget(form.date.day) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.time.hour, { 'attr': { 'size': '1' } }) }}:{{ form_widget(form.time.minute, { 'attr': { 'size': '1' } }) }}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock datetime_widget %}
```

And here's how to implement the second option:

```
{% extends 'form_div_layout.html.twig' %}

{% block date_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% if widget == 'single_text' %}
        {{ block('field_widget') }}
    {% else %}
        {{ date_pattern|replace({
            '{{ year }}':  form_widget(form.year),
            '{{ month }}': form_widget(form.month),
            '{{ day }}':   form_widget(form.day),
        })|raw }}
    {% endif %}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock date_widget %}

{% block time_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% if widget == 'single_text' %}
        {{ block('field_widget') }}
    {% else %}
        {{ form_widget(form.hour, { 'attr': { 'size': '1' } }) }}:{{ form_widget(form.minute, { 'attr': { 'size': '1' } }) }}{% if with_seconds %}:{{ form_widget(form.second, { 'attr': { 'size': '1' } }) }}{% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock time_widget %}
```

Then the date & time will be together in the same div. Obviously you could add some space between the date and time by adding in your desired html

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thx for the reply! It's telling me that "Variable 'date_pattern' does not exist"

Comment: aha, yes it would normally get that from symfony's DateType class. It just specifies the format of the date, so you can replace the variable with '{{ year }}-{{ month }}-{{ day }}', or rearrange as you like

Comment: Am getting this error now: A hash key must be followed by a colon (:). Unexpected token "punctuation" of value "(" ("punctuation" expected with value ":") (I've edited my first post)

Comment: Solved above problem. But now I'm getting: Method "day" for object "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView" does not exist

Comment: Yes that's what I'm getting too. Still investigating :)

Comment: I've updated the answer to one that works. The trick was to extend the built-in widgets (form_div_layout.html.twig). Phew!