# Symfony2, DateTime formatting with date and time together

Tags: php, date, symfony, formatting

I have created a field for publish date (with time), but I found only date formating. My time field is under my date field and it looks strange (for me), like this:

```
[DAY] [MONTH] [YEAR]
[HOURS]:[MINUTES]
```

How can i format it like this?

```
[DAY] [MONTH] [YEAR] - [HOURS]:[MINUTES]
```

There it is, what I now have in my Form builder:

```
$builder->add('published', 'datetime', array('label' => 'Date of publish', 'date_format' => 'ddMMMMyyyy', 'empty_value' => array('year' => 'Year', 'month' => 'Month', 'day' => 'Day'), 'invalid_message' => 'Date is not valid',))
```

PS: I'm using selection.

Comment: Does this help: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/date.html#reference-forms-type-date-format ?

Comment: @cheesemacfly I don't want tu use plain input text. I want using selection.

Comment: _I want using selection_ So why not writing it in your question? Calling it _your date field_ is ambiguous. Please update your question.

Comment: Sure, it's updated for you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had the same problem once and solved it using the [answer of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9708470/form-theming-datetime-widget-symfony-2):

- [Form theming datetime widget Symfony 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9708470/form-theming-datetime-widget-symfony-2).

Also, find more info on the matter by browsing the [following section](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html) of the [Symfony2 official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/index.html).

- [How to customize Form Rendering](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html).

Comment: you can and should start from the form theming found in the symfony vendors... i don;t remember where exactly but it's there

Comment: I found it only as form_widget(form.date) in original layout. So I'll use this tut and just force update. Then thanks for help :)