# Symfony4 forms DateTimeType field order

Tags: forms, symfony, datetime, twig, symfony4

I am using a form in symfony 4 with the DateTimeType.

twig is ordering the fields by international DateTime format: month, day, year, hour, minute.

I'm using this code:

`$form = $this->createFormBuilder($task)
->add('start', DateTimeType::class, array('widget' => 'choice', 'format' => 'dd-MM-yyyy')
->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'neuen Termin anlegen'))
->getForm();`

Twig will output this:

[image: result is]

How can I order the fields by german DateTime format? like this (day, month, year, hour, minute):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `format` is the correct option for [widget](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/datetime.html#widget) = `choice` to render a [datetime field](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/datetime.html) as select-inputs since:

> Defines the widget option for both the DateType and TimeType. This can
>   be overridden with the date_widget and time_widget options.

1. So going with the format option should look like this:

   ```
   'format' => 'dd-MM-yyyy  HH:mm'
   ```
2. or if you try the second optoin and override both settings, e.g.

   ```
   $builder->add('myDate', 'datetime', array(
       'date_widget' => 'single_text',
       'time_widget' => 'choice',
       ...
   ));
   ```
3. Another option is, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40419920/8291949), using form_widget for each datetime component separately:

   ```
   {{ form_widget(form.date.date.day) }}
   {{ form_widget(form.date.date.month) }}
   {{ form_widget(form.date.date.year) }}
   {{ form_widget(form.date.time.hour) }}
   {{ form_widget(form.date.time.minute) }}
   ```

   [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9709749/8291949) answer goes further and explores ways to customize the dateime fields even more.

BTW: The symfony form builder expects the date format in [RFC format](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime#TOC-Date-Time-Format-Syntax). Don't confuse them with the PHP date format options, e.g. `'yyyy-MM-dd HH:i'`.